# Linking a Metal library at compile time

Tags: ios, metal

I have a Metal library (file ending in `.metallib`) and I would like to link it in another project. My issue is that no matter how is specify the `-L` and `-l` flags the Metal compiler/linker doesn't ever seem to be able to link the library and thus I get an "undefined symbols" error from my project. What is the correct way of linking a Metal Library to your own library at compile time?

Comment: I don't think you can "link" them together. Think of the API, you are opening a single `MTLLibrary` from a file and then load functions from it. It's a single library, it can't link against anything unless you use dynamic libraries and linked functions. But that's not compile time linking in a sense of compiling metal libs. It will link those libraries when you are compiling pipelines at runtime.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Thank you! Indeed it seems linking a metallib file doesn't really make sense for the reasons you stated, which made me reconsider what I was doing and try to better understand if there could be some other way around it. I think there is some "hack" for doing something quite similar: by using .air files instead, you can actually pass them the the Metal linker (with `-Xlinker pathToYourAIRFile`)

Comment: Yeah, air is kind of like an object file. You can link multiples of them into a metallib.